# Which countries don't have a strong “car culture” (noisy cars & bikes)?

Tags: united-kingdom, europe, culture

I currently live in Wales. Like most of the UK, it has a very high rate of people driving extremely loud cars and motorbikes, at all times of the day. Like a lot of people, the noise annoys me, but the police do nothing. It's like this in many other countries, i.e. Germany.

So my question is, which countries don't have a high incidence / culture of people driving loud cars, whilst also being relatively well populated? (whilst Greenland would probably not have this, it's also not a very practical country to live in). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

France may be what you are looking for, because of high taxes on powerful cars, a car such as a Mustang costs more or less 40k€ in which you have to add at least 20k€ of Eco Malus on top of that, meaning that even though there are people that are passionate about cars, it becomes more and more difficult to own such cars.

Also what you have to consider is the amount of electric cars. France has not a high rate electric cars compared to some other countries, I heard that many Dutch people own an electric car, which may be a good answer as well.